# How to use pattern-dependent variables in dependencies in make pattern rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'd like to define a GNU make pattern rule with the dependencies in a pattern-dependent variable.  What I'd like is something like this:

```
%.exe : $(%_EXE_SOURCES) $(%_EXE_RESOURCES)
    $(CSC_V)$(CSC) $(CSCFLAGS) $($*_EXE_CSCFLAGS) -target:exe \
            -out:$@ $($*_EXE_SOURCES) $($*_EXE_RESOURCES)
```

And to later define something like

```
FOO_EXE_SOURCES = src/Foo.cs
all: Foo.exe
```

The rule presented works to build; in the body of the rule the `$($*_EXE_SOURCES)` variable is expanded to `$(FOO_EXE_SOURCES)`, which expands to `src/Foo.cs`.  The dependencies don't expand properly, however; changing src/Foo.cs does not cause Foo.exe to be rebuilt.

I suspect that this can't actually be done in make, but perhaps someone has a work-alike make fragment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use "secondary expansion". Something like this should accomplish what you are looking for:

```
Foo_EXE_SOURCES := foo.cs bar.cs baz.cs
all: Foo.exe

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.exe: $$($$*_EXE_SOURCES)
    $(CSC_V)$(CSC) $(CSCFLAGS) $($*_EXE_CSCFLAGS) -target:exe \
            -out:$@ $($*_EXE_SOURCES) $($*_EXE_RESOURCES)
```

Enabling secondary expansion allows the use of automatic variables (i.e. `$*` in this case) in the prerequesites list, which is something that would otherwise *not* work.

Comment: Excellent.  That looks like it's exactly what I'm after.